# Jquery Validation Remote JSON not working with Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-mobile, jquery-validate

I've scoured this site and others trying to find an answer to my issue. I'm using jQuery Mobile 1.1.1, jQuery 1.7.2, jQuery Validation 1.9. and a JSON service that returns boolean.

The below remote call works great in any computer browser, but does not work in mobile browsers.

```
remote: {
    url:'https://myjsonservice/check.json',
    type:"POST",
    dataType:'jsonp',
    dataFilter:function(data) {
        if( data == "true" ) {return success;}
    }
},
```

Any ideas on how I can get this working with mobile browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Came across this and it was never answered.

You should try it with regular JSON.  If your web service is on another domain just make a same-domain proxy.

If you dont want to do that try:  [JSONP calls not working with apple-mobile-web-app-capable="yes"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747264/jsonp-calls-not-working-with-apple-mobile-web-app-capable-yes)